# Issues in running examples given in Omnet inet framework

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am new to omnet++. I run omnet++5 in my Windows 7 32-bit PC. When I run inet examples, it is showing this error:

> Error during the network setup:(omnetpp::cCanvas)WirelessC.canvas: Error creating figure from NED property @figure[rcvdPkText]: No figure
>   class registered with name 'IndicatorTextFigure' or
>   'cIndicatorTextFigure'.

[image]

Comment: Have you built `INET`?

Comment: yes, using "make mode=release" command.